# Error Message still appears with >nul 2>nul

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

The batch file outputs "The system cannot find the file specified." instead of redirecting the error to `nul`

```
set /p firstline=<text.txt >nul 2>nul
pause
```

What do I need to to do suppress error messages

Comment: You don't actually have >nul in the above code.

Comment: im sry something goes wrong with the code output....

Answer (score 1):

With this code redirection will be ignored. I'm not sure why, my guess is that because error happens in redirection mechanism itself, later redirs will never run.

To force separation of redirections where you expect errors - use ():

```
(set /p firstline=<text.txt) >nul 2>nul
```

You can also consider using different syntax to redirect everything to one ouptut:

```
(set /p firstline=<foo2.txt) >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

That does appear to be the case (tested on Win7).  Seems like a bug-like feature. :-)  If your batch file is simple enough, you could get around this by calling your batch file with `2>nul` (i.e., `foo.cmd 2>nul`).

Alternately, you could put just that line in a batch file of its own (say, `setfirstline.cmd`) and use `call setfirstline.cmd 2>nul` from a "parent" batch file.  Hacky, but functional.